# Docker - how to set image name

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have docker image which is created with `docker-compose`. There are 2 containers inside image. I need to change image name from `8_flask_nginx_docker` to e.g. `jodynek/flask-nginx:0.0.1.RELEASE`. Is it possible inside `docker-compose.yml`? Thanks for help.

[image: Generated image]

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.9'  

services:
  web-app:
    image: jodynek/flask-nginx:0.0.1.RELEASE
    build: .
    command: python main.py
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"

  nginx-proxy:
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - "8888:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    depends_on:
      - web-app
```

Comment: have you tried `container_name`? https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#container_name

Comment: Yes, I tried it. This change container name only, not the image name (tag).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the project name and you can set it up with `-p` option.

`docker compose -p my-project-name up`.

If you want to set a custom container name:

```
services:
  web-app:
    container_name: my-web-container // <--- name here
    image: jodynek/flask-nginx:0.0.1.RELEASE
    build: .
    command: python main.py
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"

  nginx-proxy:
    container_name: my-proxy // <-- name here
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - "8888:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    depends_on:
      - web-app
```